# Stay on my activity when dialing

Tags: android

I am using the intent with ACTION_CALL to make call in my app:

```
str="tel:0123456789";
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
intent.setData(Uri.parse(str));
startActivity(intent);
```

But it pops up the system dialing screen. I understand this is built into ROM and can not be customized. But Can I hide this screen and keep the user staying on my activity?

Did some googling and research here. But no clear answer so far.

Comment: The user needs access to the in-call screen to toggle speakerphone mode, interact with touch-tone menus, etc. Please do not interfere with this.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can't customize the dialing screen, but you can use a PhoneStateListener to get certain information about the phone call. See [this link](http://androidapps.org.ua/i_sect18_d1e18123.html).

Comment: But I want to show my screen to user rather than the dialing screen. Basically, I'd like to handle phone calls in my app without leaving my app, including inputting numbers, dialing, hangup, etc.

Comment: I suggest going through the tutorial in the link (you might want to start one chapter back), but I'm not sure it's possible. Here's a quote from section 15.1.2 (Limitations on What Applications Can Do with the Phone): "Some readers may be disappointed to see that the android.telephony package limits their access to getting information, and does not provide direct control over the dialer or the state of a call." If you use listeners and find some way to hide the dialer, maybe you could make something work, but I can't read the whole tutorial for you.