# Android - Come back on my activity during a call

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-dialer

After have searched since more hour, I've found this about my problem ([Stay on my activity when dialing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12556790/stay-on-my-activity-when-dialing))
but a negative answer.

My project consist to help a handicap (deaf people). I want to launch a call since my app and go back to my app (like return button) to show voice data.

Currently, I just need to do system like return button and I ask you in order to get help !

To call a number :

```
Intent dial = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + "666-666-666"));
dial.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_USER_ACTION);
startActivity(dial);
```

And I've a PhoneStateListener to know the state of the CALL.

The link I've shared's the only one I've found to this subject.

Thanks for reading.